# how to check if a std::map insert fails in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a custom data structure `Class Client` and `ClientList`.

In ClientList I do

```
map<ULONG, Client*> list;
```

and then I add elements by

```
void ClientList::add(Client *client) {
list.insert(std::pair<ULONG,Client*>(client->getID(),client));
}
```

how to check if `insert` fails?

Comment: We need a definition of "fails" to answer this correctly.

Comment: When you have a new question, ask a new question, don't edit your current one to also ask for the new stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) returns a `pair< iterator, bool >` where the `bool` indicates if the item has been inserted or if the key is already present in the list. If the key is already present, the iterator will point to this item.

Comment: I am somewhat new to this, but how do I check the bool value for true or false when a pair is returned?

Comment: @JustinPeel The first is always free. 

You will have to consult the pair documentation to solve the next question. You will manage.

Comment: std::pair<iterator,bool> result;  doesnt work, what to use instead of iterator?

Comment: @user494461 `map<ULONG, Client*>::iterator` You really need a C++ book before you continue any of this.

Comment: Or `auto result = ...` for c++11 (maybe previous versions also)

Answer (score 1):

from cplusplus.it

> `pair<iterator,bool> insert ( const value_type& x );` returns a pair, with its member pair::first set to an iterator pointing to either the newly inserted element or to the element that already had its same value in the map. The pair::second element in the pair is set to true if a new element was inserted or false if an element with the same value existed.